current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_OrderGrid data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_OrderGrid data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
#1 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#3 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#4 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:76]


Add the module version (1.0.0) into the module.xml file in following way

Then rerun the Following command
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f

Please let me know if your issue is resolved or not.


Upload the proper package of this extension : Wac_OrderGrid

Run the following command from the CLI.
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/



